# How to avoid JavaScript/CSS injections with tinymce on Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

If I want allow user to add some formating, but I need prevent css and javascript injections. Any solution how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TinyMCE has the ability to restrict the types of tags that users can enter - see [the documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration) for `valid_elements` and `invalid_elements`.